# How to resolve "used command not allowed" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

This post isn't duplicate. I already referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437689/error-1148-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819098/error-1148-mysql-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version) but the answers doesn't help

I am trying to execute a code in mySQL client window. HowEVER,I get the below error

> The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

What I did

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

[image]

I executed the above commands in `MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client`

When I tried to do the same thing in `MySQL Shell`, I get the below error as `Unexpected identifier`

[image]

I am assuming `MySQL Shell` is the server. Do we have to do this at both client and server side?

How do I resolve this? In addition, whenever I launch command line client, I am only prompted to **type password. So I am not able to pass it as a parameter**. my clinet looks like as shown below

[image]

But how do I pass the below parameters while logging in then?

```
mysql -u abcd -p password_here --local-infile=1
```

I am new to MySQL and can you guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1:**

To run sql commands in `MySQL Shell` you need to change from default `JS` to `sql`

**R1:**

type `\sql` to change from `js` to `sql` 
`mysql-js> \sql`

**Q2:**
*so I am not able to pass it as a parameter*

For this you must be selecting 'MySQL x.x Command Line Client' under windows search.

To resolve you need to have mysql `bin` folder in environment path or do the below step to access

**R2:**

Goto "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x\bin" this is windows default path unless you change.

Then in the address bar if you click it will select ( i.e. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin) there just type cmd (Note: now in the address bar you will see only cmd) then press enter.

Once cmd window opens with the mysql path like below

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>`

Type blah..blah.. blah

`mysql -u abcd -p password_here --local-infile=1`

**Note:** If you just parse `-p` instead of `-ppassword` it will ask for password after that. So if you are going to type the password directly then type `-pyourpass` there will not be any spaces between `-p` and password