# Not permitted LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I'm trying to execute this command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/ICD9/CMS32_DESC_SHORT_DX.txt' INTO TABLE icd9_dx_code FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' (@var) SET revision = 0, dx_code = trim(Substring(@var, 1, 5)),short_desc = trim(Substring(@var, 7, 60))
```

but phpmyadmin shows me that error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVl9U.png)

Actually the error means that "The command isn't permitted in this Version of MariaDB.

I've read on internet and this is because the command has too many security vulnerabilities.

Somebody knows the correct way to load data local infile?

or a command with similar result?

Hope you'll have a great day, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 1148 MySQL The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819098/error-1148-mysql-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version)

Comment: What is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';`?